# How to compute several logistic model at the same time and summary p-value

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I am trying to compute several model in the same time. The dependent variable in the first column, as rest of them are independent columns. I want to run logistic regression between IV and DV for each independent variables separately. Thank you very much for your help! Please let me know anything needs to be provided.

**** Some of IV are bivariate variables. So it should be treated as.factor in R.

*** After compute each model, can I also compute a p-value for each model in one time.

*** Right now, I just compute and summary each model separately

The data and my current code looks like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqfBQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pODpq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you. Please read also [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Pictures of your data are not as helpful as providing a sample of your data with `dput()`. Also you should paste your code directly into your question and not paste a picture. Here is an example using the `iris` data set that is included with R:

```
data(iris)
iris.2 <- iris[iris$Species!="setosa", ]
iris.2 <- droplevels(iris.2)
iris.2$Species <- as.numeric(iris.2$Species) - 1
# Species: 0 == versicolor, 1== virginica
str(iris.2)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  7 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.2 3.2 3.1 2.3 2.8 2.8 3.3 2.4 2.9 2.7 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  4.7 4.5 4.9 4 4.6 4.5 4.7 3.3 4.6 3.9 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  1.4 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.6 1 1.3 1.4 ...
#  $ Species     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Now we compute the logistic regression in which `Species` is the dependent variable against each of the independent variables.

```
forms <- paste("Species ~", colnames(iris.2)[-5])
forms
# [1] "Species ~ Sepal.Length" "Species ~ Sepal.Width"  "Species ~ Petal.Length" "Species ~ Petal.Width" 
iris.glm <- lapply(forms, function(x) glm(as.formula(x), iris.2, family=binomial))
```

Now `iris.glm` is a list containing all of the results. The results of the first logistic regression are `iris.glm[[1]]` and `summary(iris.glm[[1]])` gives you the summary. To print all of the results use `lapply()`:

```
lapply(iris.glm, print)
lapply(iris.glm, summary)
```